# Why doesn't Java play sounds over Bluetooth headset?

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth

So on my machine I have Bluetooth working fine, I can stream audio to it and record from it, except when I run a Java program that has sound. The sound files work through regular speakers but they don't get forwarded to the headset. My current operating System is Lubuntu 10.04.

My code to play a sound is:

```
public static void playSound(File sound) {
    try {
        AudioClip cp = Applet.newAudioClip(sound.toURL());
        cp.play();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Applet.newAudioClip() method is pretty darn old.  Like Java 1.0 old.  Since then Java has rewritten a lot of it's sound APIs.  I bet whatever code is playing that sound doesn't take into account the various audio settings of the OS.  The javax.sound.sampled package has the new APIs, and while they are harder to learn, they give you much more control over how the sound is played and modified.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html

You could test out to see if Java can play that audio over your bluetooth by downloading

http://www.javazoom.net/index.shtml

And try playing an MP3 see if that goes over your bluetooth headset.

Comment: I implemented the new library and the same problem occurs. any idea of what it could be?